# How to render in cycles like when you use backface culling in eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I want this model to render like this:

[image: Render1]

this is done by using backface culling in eevee rendering.

In cycles, however, it's rendering like this:

[image: Render2]

I know there's a node set-up in cycles to recreate backface culling, however it did not work and only made the model look glitchy.

Any help would be nice. For reference, here's the model I am using if anyone would want to experiment with it:

https://www.models-resource.com/nintendo_switch/supersmashbrosultimate/model/30311/

Comment: Would you happen to be on 3.1, by chance? 3.1 introduced a new (and incredibly annoying) artifact with Cycles where overlapping geometry will turn odd colors (usually very dark shades or just black). https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.1/Cycles#Ray_Tracing_Precision
"Such overlapping geometry should be removed, or have a small distance added in between."
I downloaded and inspected the Ganon model you posted, and it looks like there's a fair amount of overlapping geometry going on. Either by clever shader or mesh editing you can overcome it. Or... maybe try 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a setup I use

[image]

**WARNING*** WITH SOLID MESH YOU MAY HAVE TO TURN OFF SHADOWS

[image]

**If you don't want to turn off shadows** use this setup here:

[image]

Comment: This still didn't work unfortunately. Any other set-ups I could use?

Comment: If transparent doesn’t want to work, use a Glass shader and set the IOR to 1 and roughness to 0

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately.... I think I might just be doomed here.

Comment: I should also add that I've tried this with multiple models that had the backface culling problem and none of the setups worked. Is there an addon to add backface culling to cycles by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Using Marux's setup above, but switching the "Is Shadow Ray" to "Is Diffuse Ray" fixed the issue I was dealing with on my personal project, which was tweaking an Inverted Hull outline to work in Cycles.